# After upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04, Alt-F2 does not work

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04.  When I tried to use alt-F2 it brings up the file/video/photo/application search window instead of allowing me to run a specific command.

Updated with screenshot of keyboard shortcuts:

[image: Updated with screenshot of keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: Try alt-fn-f2. Report back.

Comment: alt-fn-f2: nothing happens.  Not even the search window.

Comment: Just to clarify... it should be alt+f2 or alt+fn+f2.

Comment: alt-fn-f2 does nothing
alt-f2 shows the activity search window

Comment: alt+fn+f2 works on my 20.04 VM. You're holding all three keys at the same time, yes?

Comment: yes, holding all 3 keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved.  Somehow during the upgrade I got switched to Unity instead of GNOME.  Switching back solved all my problems.

Comment: How would your solution apply to Lubuntu 20.04 LTS? As for me, Alt + F2 doesn't work either and I'm not sure what steps exactly are necessary to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

this launcher is related to your keyboard shortcuts.

You can check your keyboard shortcuts in settings and look at option "Show the run command prompt" in the "System Area".

Comment: There is no "Show the run command prompt" in the "System Area".  The only two entries are: "Log out" and "Lock screen".  How can I add it back?

Comment: Please, go to Settings-> Keyboard Shortcuts and search for a Area labeled System. In this area you can find the "Show the run command prompt" field.

Comment: There is no such option there in System.  Just "Log out" and "Lock screen".  See the screenshot in the updated question.

Comment: You can set your shortcut using the following command
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-run-dialog "['<Alt>F2']`

If you want to reset all gnome shortcuts, you can run
`gsettings reset-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`

Answer (score 0):

For those which are on KDE you have to go from "Run Command" to "KRunner"

This is located in "Global Shortcuts" in the components sidebar.